# Reset input on click, vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I would like to have my text fields empty when I click "add task" button. How could I achieve that?

```html
<template>
  <div class="col-md-6" >
    <div class="card bg-light mt-4">
      <div class="card-header">Task Form</div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <form action="./api/word" method="post" @submit.prevent="addTask()">

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="title" v-model="title" placeholder="Local word" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="second_title" v-model="second_title" placeholder="Foreign word" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn btn-info">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      second_title: ''
    }

  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted.')
  },
  methods: {

    addTask() {
      Event.$emit('taskCreated', {
        title: this.title,
        second_title: this.second_title
      });
      axios.post('./api/word', {
        title: this.title,
        second_title: this.second_title,

      })
      this.title = '';
      this.second_title = '';


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, in the addTask() just add event as parameter and in the end of the function you write: `event.target.reset();`

Code:

```
<template>
  <div class="col-md-6" >
    <div class="card bg-light mt-4">
      <div class="card-header">Task Form</div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <form action="./api/word" method="post" @submit.prevent="addTask">

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="title" v-model="title" placeholder="Local word" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="second_title" v-model="second_title" placeholder="Foreign word" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn btn-info">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And there:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      second_title: ''
    }

  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted.')
  },
  methods: {

    addTask(event) {
      Event.$emit('taskCreated', {
        title: this.title,
        second_title: this.second_title
      });
      axios.post('./api/word', {
        title: this.title,
        second_title: this.second_title,

      })
      this.title = '';
      this.second_title = '';

      event.target.reset();
    }
```

Hope it works for you ; )

Comment: TypeError: e.target.reset is not a function